# Employee Leave Date computation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, date-range

Am working on a problem where i have a start date and number of days, so when an employee asks for leave for lets say 20 days, so the procedure is add the days to that date, without including  weekends and holidays so as to get the date this person should resume work. here is what i have been working with so far. but am failing to get a real final date,

// function sorts out holiday

```
 function isHoliday(dt, arr){
     var bln = false;
        for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             if (compare(dt, arr[i])) { //If days are not holidays
                bln = true;
                break;
                  }
         }
          return bln;
   }
```

// the function below helps in the holiday comparison procedure

```
    function compare(dt1, dt2){
        var equal = false;
            if(dt1.getDate() == dt2.getDate() && dt1.getMonth() == dt2.getMonth() && dt1.getFullYear() == dt2.getFullYear()) {
            equal = true;
        }
        return equal;
    }
```

now in my main function i try to use sort out holidays and weekends and add days to the start date so i can archive the end date. i think am going wrong somewhere in this code and now am stack ..

```
    function returnfinaldate()
    {
     var holiday = [];

    var cy = new Date().getFullYear();
    holiday[0] = new Date(cy, 1, 01);
    holiday[1] = new Date(cy, 1, 26);
    holiday[2] = new Date(cy, 2, 16);
    holiday[3] = new Date(cy, 3, 08);
    holiday[4] = new Date(cy, 3, 20);
    holiday[5] = new Date(cy, 4, 14);
    holiday[6] = new Date(cy, 4, 16);
    holiday[7] = new Date(cy, 4, 17);
    holiday[8] = new Date(cy, 5, 01);
    holiday[9] = new Date(cy, 5, 14);
    holiday[10] = new Date(cy, 6, 03);
    holiday[11] = new Date(cy, 6, 09);
    holiday[12] = new Date(cy, 6, 21);
    holiday[13] = new Date(cy, 6, 21);
    holiday[14] = new Date(cy, 6, 26);
    holiday[15] = new Date(cy, 9, 02);
    holiday[16] = new Date(cy, 9, 22);
    holiday[17] = new Date(cy, 10, 09);
    holiday[18] = new Date(cy, 12, 21);
    holiday[19] = new Date(cy, 12, 25);
    holiday[20] = new Date(cy, 12, 26);

    var startDate = new Date();
    var endDate = new Date(); 

    startDate='8/1/2017';

    noOfDaysToAdd = 7, count = 0;

    while (count < noOfDaysToAdd) {
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+1)
        // Date.getDay() gives weekday starting from 0(Sunday) to
        // 6(Saturday)
        if (endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6 && !isHoliday(endDate, holiday)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return endDate;
    }
```

The final date am getting is wrong. need some help here.

Comment: Your `endDate` is based on current date not the string version of `startDate`

Answer (score -1):

Here use start date as starting point of calculation of days else your logic seems fine

```
function returnfinaldate() {
            var holiday = [];
            holiday[0] = new Date(2017, 9, 5);// holiday 1
            holiday[1] = new Date(2017, 9, 6);//holiday 2


            var startDate = new Date();
            var endDate = new Date();

            startDate = new Date(2017, 7, 1);// '8/1/2017';

            noOfDaysToAdd = 7, count = 0;
            endDate = startDate;
      //use below code to include start date in count else comment below code
          //  if (endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6 && !isHoliday(endDate, holiday)) {
             //   count++;
           // }
            while (count < noOfDaysToAdd) {
                endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1)
                // Date.getDay() gives weekday starting from 0(Sunday) to
                // 6(Saturday)
                if (endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6 && !isHoliday(endDate, holiday)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return endDate;
        }
```

Comment: Thanx mr Yogesh . you just saved my life. it does work so well

Comment: i have just realized initializing  endDate = startDate;  is giving an endDate with extra month ahead

Comment: While creating start date make month starting from 0 like for August its 7, if that is correct then please provide me example i will look into it

Comment: In the current code now i notice the errors where if i want to get the end date when i add 7 days to 8/1/2017 it gives me a friday 8‎/‎25‎/‎2017 
which is wrong, its supposed to give me 8/‎9/‎2017 and lets say i have two holidays in between like 8/3/2017 and 8/7/2017, the system should
skip those two days and give me 8/11/2017 after adding 7 days to that date, and the other. and after this, the system should be able to give me the  resume date that is to say, the end date plus one  but resume date can not be a weekend or any  of the holidays.

Comment: ie (if end date is 8/11/2017 then add 1 day to get resume date but that resume day must be a week day not a weekend or hoilday)

Comment: Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/ywpow2cr/1/  It will explain all days in message, Let me know if any scenario is missing

Comment: Yogesh . your the best. although you could check out some clarity and tell me if its okay. on the month of April . we have two holidays thats, 14th and 17th, now if i say i want to begin from 3rd and add 15 days ... resume date here, i thought end date is 24, and resume date is 25. i dont know but the rest looks okay

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with your date here https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/ywpow2cr/2/ in this case you will have 25th as end date and next working day as 26th which is Wednesday. If you would like to include 3 april in calculation then date will come as 24 as end date and 25th as resume date, currently logic starts calculating from 4th april

Comment: am sorry to get back to this question. but are we talking about the same calender because in my country the public holidays are fixed, am going to update them in the orignal question, but when i add them as public holidays, the logic goes off track. really need help here

Comment: Bels could you please update your holiday list in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/2vo4ep4h/ let me know scenarios which are not working

Comment: I have updated the fiddle, but it looks like,  if i have a start date of 2017/3/3 and i add 15 days to it even if its 5 days with or without holidays - it reads the month of April, and the fiddle is saved as local, i dont   know if u can see my updates

Comment: if not then the months have been updated in my orignal question on this page,

Comment: Here in  your list of holidays you have taken month as starting index from 1 but it should be from 0 - January to 11-December Please find this updated fiddle to check i have converted your holidays in propert format with starting date from 3 March which is new Date(2017,2,3)  https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/2vo4ep4h/6/

Comment: So according to your fiddle. if my months begin from 0 - 9, how do i get my start date to read jan holidays . ie startDate = new Date(2017, 1, 3);, in holiday list holiday[0] = new Date(cy, 0, 01); . because what i was doing was to get feb in my date picker i pick a feb date but reduce the month by one. startDate = new Date(2017, 2-1, 3); but this methord has issues with jan, is there any way the holiday list can be adjusted in numbering without affecting the entire code?